# Zend Framework 2.4: Redirect results in blank page on server, works locally

Tags: php, redirect, installation, zend-framework2, server

### Introduction

- Me and my team are using the **Zend Framework 2.4.2** for the first time
- Our goal is to build a simple portal with an **authorization module** and table- or list-based content
- We've been working on this for a few weeks now and haven't found a solution to our problem yet

### Problem

In general, Zend works perfectly on a local machine using XAMPP Apache. However, when deploying it on a remote server, everything works **except for redirects**. 
Whenever there is a command like

```
      return $this->redirect()->toRoute('foo');
```

the browser just shows a blank page (though it redirects perfectly on XAMPP).

### System

- We use the [Zend Skeleton Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) with the [Album Modul](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html). We also implemented an authorization module which works very similarly and uses redirects in the same fashion.
- Locally, we use XAMPP Version 1.8.3 and PHP 5.5.15.
- We tested our application on two servers (1&1 and Strato) and different PHP versions (5.3, 5.5, 5.6). All of the configurations result in the same behavior (blank page when redirecting).

### What we ruled out

- Case sensitivity and path-related causes can be ruled out. When Zend cannot find a path, it shows an error message.
- Different PHP versions have been tested, so the version is probably not a cause. We cannot say the same about the configuration.
- Access rights on the server can be ruled out as a cause. We tried different configurations here.

*We researched a lot on redirects and server configuration, but noone else seems to have this problem. In fact no one ever talks about problems on the server, just general problems with the framework. We are thankful for every thought and idea.*

Comment: Did you check error log?

Comment: We checked a bunch of things via Firebug and Fiddler. No sign of any error. We are currently looking for a way to let Zend write an error log, let me know of you know a good way to do that.

Comment: It should happen by default. 'Blank page' means an error occurred, but `display_errors` is off (which is the ZF default). Check the web server error log on your production server.

Comment: I did check the error log on my production server. It simply logs a GET request, but nothing after that. Is there any way to activate a ZF error log?

Comment: Are you sure that's the error_log? Successful GET requests shouldn't appear there. A quick fix might be to temporarily add `ini_set('display_errors', true);` to your `public/index.php` (remove it afterwards).

Comment: Yes, that was definitely the log file.

Answer (score 0):

### I finally found a solution!

I needed to make a copy of my local php.ini file and paste it in the public/ folder of my Zend application. The server behaves in a way that it loads a standard php.ini if there is none. Now it uses the php.ini with the correct settings. Apparently, there are some few settings necessary for Zend's redirects to work. Naturally, I had to comment out all of the local paths in the copy of the php.ini.
Nevertheless, thank you for your input!